# Get file details (complete file path) from the filename (only basename) existing as a text in tkinter Text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

With the help of following code I am inserting the filename (file basename) in the tkinter Text widget and subsequently then trying to print the complete file path after the "Get Data" button is pressed.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import os

root=tk.Tk()    

ent=tk.Text(root)
ent.grid(row=1,column=0)

def addfile():
    filename =askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Tiff files","*.tif"),("All files","*.*")))
    ent.insert(tk.INSERT, '"' + os.path.basename(filename) + '"') 
    ent.insert(tk.INSERT, "\n")

def getfile():
    print(ent.get("1.0", tk.END))

b=tk.Button(root,text="Select File",command=addfile)
b.grid(row=0,column=0)

b1 = tk.Button(root,text="Get Data",command=getfile)
b1.grid(row=2,column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

After running the above code only filenames are getting printed (without filepath).

Now basically what I want is that, after the "Get Data" button is pressed (where the contents of Text widget is read) then complete path of files should be printed.

Additional information:-

I know that if filenames would have been different then I could have used dictionary (key, value) pair to link basename of each file with its absolute path. But issue will come when different files present in different folder location but having same names are added to the Text widget.

Comment: I would recommend to edit the Q with a what you expect vs what you got, to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

As Cool Cloud has commented it is hard to give the exact answer you need, because you havent told us what is happening and what you expect/what to happen.

The way I read it is that you either want:

1. the whole filename, which you have recieved from the `askopenfilename()` to be inserted in the `Text` widget.
2. you want the whole filename to be printed when you click the `Button` `b1`, but the `Text` widget to be left as is.

**1.** I would change `def addfile():` to

```
def addfile():
    filename = askopenfilename()
    ent.insert(tk.INSERT, '"' + filename + '"\n')
```

What this does is inserts the full file path rather than just the basename, i.e. it would insert `"D:/example/help.tif"` rather than just `help.tif`.

**2.** I would use the code below

```
root = tk.Tk()

def addfile():
    filename = askopenfilename()
    list_of_filenames.append(filename)
    ent.insert(tk.INSERT, '"' + os.path.basename(filename) + '"\n') 

def getfile():
    for i in range(len(list_of_filenames)):
        print(list_of_filesnames[i])
                   

list_of_filenames = []

ent = tk.Text(root)
ent.grid(row=1, column=0)

b=tk.Button(root,text="Select File",command=addfile)
b.grid(row=0,column=0)

b1 = tk.Button(root,text="Get Data",command=getfile)
b1.grid(row=2,column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

What I have done is create a global list variable named `list_of_filenames` and in `def addfile():` I added the line `list_of_filenames.append(filename)`, this takes the file you selected, and the path, and add it to the list variable. Thus giving you a list with every file you select, and it can be accessed by any function you build because it is global.

The final change is to `def getfile():` this can be done exactly how you would like to, I have written it to print each of the files individually on a seperate lines, without square brackets or quotation marks.

Using the same example as in part 1, if I selected a file with the path `D:/example/help.tif` the `Text` widget would read "help.tif" and when `b1` is clicked `D:/example/help.tif` would be printed to the consol.

Comment: My doubt is suppose if I add 2 files (present in different folders say D:/example1/help.tif, D:/example2/help.tif) in text widget, then in the text widget 2 "help.tif" entries will be present. Now as it is a text widget if I delete any one of the help.tif entry from the text widget and then press Get Data button, then it would print help.tif. So how do I come to know that this help.tif is corresponding to which folder "example1" or "example2".

Comment: Does the ```Text``` widget have to read ```"help.tif"``` twice in your example when you have 2 ```"help.tif"```, or could you have ```"help.tif"``` and ```"example2/help.tif"``` if a base name is repeated?

Comment: In the current scenario I have added 2 help.tif files (corresponding to two different folders i.e. example1 and example2) to the text widget. Now these 2 help.tif files corresponds to two different paths i.e. "D:/example1/help.tif", "D:/example2/help.tif". Now suppose if I delete one help.tif file manually (other help.tif file still present in the text widget) and then press the Get Data button then finally I want this function to return the absolute path of the existing help.tif file to get printed.

Comment: I've done the best I can with the info you have give, I will add another answer with my code.

Answer (score 0):

I will split my code up to try and explain what i've done.

The first 4 functions are to do the `addfile():` plus the other thing you have asked for.

1. The first function `split_filename(path):` does what the fuction name says. It will take the path entered and create a list of the individual parts of the the path. (i.e. if you have `D:/folder/example/help/test.tif` it would return `['D:/', 'folder', 'example', 'help', 'test.tif']`, you will see later that this is useful when you have 2 basenames that are the same.

```
def split_filename(path):
    allParts = []
    while 1:
        parts = os.path.split(path)
        if parts[0] == path:
            allParts.insert(0, parts[0])
            break
        elif parts[1] == path:
            allParts.insert(0, parts[1])
            break
        else:
            path = parts[0]
            allParts.insert(0, parts[1])
    return allParts
```

2. `check_if_fileBasename_in_current_content(current_content, selected_file_basename):` again the function name tells you exactly what is does. This checks if the new selected  file basename is already in the `Text` widget.

```
def check_if_fileBasename_in_current_content(current_content, selected_file_basename):
    for line in current_content:
        if line == '':
            pass
        elif line == selected_file_basename:
            return True
```

3. The third `if_true_split_path_for_basename(selected_file_path, selected_file_basename):` is called if the new selected file basename already exists in the `Text` widget. The fuction takes the path for both the new selected file and the 1 already saved. If you have 2 files: `D:/example1/help.tif`(new selected) and `D:/example2/help.tif`(previously added) the new selected basename would become `example2/help.tif` instead of just `help.tif`. By doing this it makes it possible to distiquish the difference between the 2 files. At the end of the fuction the basename created thought the fuction is inserted into `ent` and added to the dictionary `dict_of_filenames`(this become useful when printing the paths when `b1` is clicked.)

```
def if_true_split_path_for_baseline(selected_file_path, selected_file_basename):
    basename_for_text_widget = []
    if selected_file_path in dict_of_filenames:
        pass
    else:
        for path, basename in dict_of_filenames.items():
            if basename == selected_file_basename:
                duplicate_path_split = split_filename(path)
                selected_file_path_split = split_filename(selected_file_path)
                for i in range(len(selected_file_path_split)):
                    duplicate_slice = duplicate_path_split[-(i + 1)]
                    selected_slice = selected_file_path_split[-(i + 1)]
                    if duplicate_slice == selected_slice:
                        basename_for_text_widget.insert(0, selected_slice)
                    else:
                        basename_for_text_widget.insert(0, selected_slice)
                        break

        ent.insert(tk.INSERT, str('/'.join(basename_for_text_widget) + '\n'))
        dict_of_filenames.update({selected_file_path: '/'.join(basename_for_text_widget)})
```

4. `addFile()` link all of the functions above, it: ask for a file; get the basename; get all of the current text is in the `Text` widget; checks if the basename already exists and if so call fuction 3 (above), and finally if it is a new basename it inserts the basename to `ent` and adds both path and basename to the dictionary.

```
def addFile():
    selected_file_path = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Tiff files", "*.tif"), ("All files", "*.*")))
    selected_file_basename = os.path.basename(selected_file_path)
    current_content = ent.get("1.0", tk.END).splitlines()

    check1 = check_if_fileBasename_in_current_content(current_content, selected_file_basename)
    basename_for_text_widget = []
    if check1:
        if_true_split_path_for_baseline(selected_file_path, selected_file_basename)

    else:
        basename_for_text_widget.append(selected_file_basename)
        dict_of_filenames.update({selected_file_path: ''.join(basename_for_text_widget)})
        ent.insert(tk.INSERT, str(' '.join(basename_for_text_widget) + '\n'))
```

Next is the `getFile():` takes the the content of `ent` and then takes the basename and prints the corresponding path.

```
def getFile():
    current_content = ent.get(1.0, tk.END).splitlines()
    for path, basename in dict_of_filenames.items():
        if basename in current_content:
            print(path)
```

The final change you need to do is to create the global dictionary
by adding `dict_of_filename = {}` Insert below the `def getFile():` fuction, with no indentation like the `Text` and `Button` variables

Everything else stays as is.